# AND/OR statements in SQL JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables: `table1` and `table2`. I can join them using `id1` or `id2`. I prefer to use `id1`, but as in some rows `id1` is missing, so I have to use `id2`. Is the following syntax correct:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 as a

LEFT JOIN table2 as b
ON (a.id1 is not null and a.id1 = b.id1) or
   (a.id2 is not null and a.id2 = b.id2)
```

It returns *some* results but I want to be sure if it is valid as I haven't seen it used before.

Are there better ways to do this?

Comment: I suggest you to add some sample data and an expected result ;).

Comment: Your syntax is entirely correct given your description.

Comment: The `is not null` is unnecessary. The comparison `a.id1 = b.id1` won't yield any "matches" for null values in `a.id1` anyway (it's equivalen to `(a.id1 = b.id1) or (a.id2 = b.id2)`. I guess you probably want something like `on (a.id1 is null and a.id2 = b.id2) or (a.id2 is null and a.id1 = b.id1)`

Comment: Then you over simplified your example to the point where you will get wrong answers....

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your concern but I think the example should be ok :)

Comment: Then why don't you simplify your condition to `(a.id1 = b.id1) or (a.id2 = b.id2)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you are probably right... So `(a.id1 = b.id1) or (a.id2 = b.id2)` works like: take `id1` but if it is missing, take `id2`, right?

Comment: Assuming 'missing' means `NULL` and not empty string.

Comment: No, there is no "preference" (or "override") in that condition. Have a look at my second condition. Note that `is null` checks a different column than the `=` condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok, thanks, your comments qualify as a great, scattered, answer to my question.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have a decent answer in the comments, but to toss another possibility into the ring, you could run both queries and union them.

```
select * 
from table1 as a
  LEFT JOIN table2 as b
    on a.id1 = b.id1
union
select * 
from table1 as a
  LEFT JOIN table2 as b
    on a.id2 = b.id2
```

The union will eliminate any duplicates between the sets, and will return records where either condition is true, much like your or statement. Performance wise, the union is probably a little slower, but gives you easier control over the sets. For instance if you only want set 2 to return results when id1 is null, just add it to the where clause. Anyway hope that helps.

Comment: UNION is often faster than OR conditions.